# Python sum of list elements with recursive function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def listsum(numList):
    if len(numList) == 1:
        return numList[0]
    else:
        return numList[0] + listsum(numList[1:])

a=[3,1,4,0,4,2]

print("Sum: ",listsum(a))
```

---

```
Sum: 12
```

The code I have written collects all the elements of the list. I would like to sum the top 5 of my list without breaking this recursive structure. When I give the value of [3,1,4,0,4,2] to the function, it should give me 12 as a result. How can i do this can you help me

Comment: Ok, have you tried *anything*? Using recursion here really doesn't make sense, so this is probably some sort of exercise, in which case, you really should try at least *something*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give a counter variable to the function:

```
def listsum(numList, counter=0):
    if len(numList) == 1 or counter == 4:
        return numList[0]
    else:
        return numList[0] + listsum(numList[1:], counter + 1)
```

This sets the value of counter to 0 if it isn't given as a parameter, so you don't have to always set it when you want to use the function. Then it checks if it has done 5 iterations or has reached the end of the list. And then you just increment it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add two parameters to a recursive function

```py
def listsum(numList, n):
    if len(numList) == 1:
        return numList[0]
    else:
        return numList[0] + listsum(numList[1:n], n-1)

a=[3,1,4,0,4,2]

print("Sum: ",listsum(a, 5))
```